# JS wont access const between scripts

Tags: javascript, html

It seems very simple but it wont work. I just want to access auth variable between index.js and auth.js but it keeps giving me error that auth is not defined in auth.js. I thought if i put the script for index.js above auth.js i would be able to use its variables in auth.js. It should be known that this all works correctly when placed in same file.

index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, intial-scale=1.0"/>
<title>yuh</title>

</head>
<body>
yo


<form id="signup-form">
  <input type="email" id="signup-email"/>
  <input type="password" id="signup-password"/>  
<button>Submit</button>

</form>

<script type="module" src="index.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="auth.js"></script>

</body>


</html>
```

index.js:

```
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword  } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.1/firebase-auth.js";
import { getFirestore} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.1/firebase-firestore.js";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "Afirebase crapYw",
    authDomain: "firebase crap",
    databaseURL: "https://firebase crap.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "firebase crap",
    storageBucket: "firebase crap.appspot.com"
   
  };

  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig); 
  const auth = getAuth(app);
  const db = getFirestore(app);
```

auth.js:

```
signupForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
e.preventDefault();

const email = signupForm['signup-email'].value;
const password = signupForm['signup-password'].value;

console.log(email, password);
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((cred) => {

  const user = cred.user;
}).catch((error) => {
  const errorCode = error.code;
  const errorMessage = error.errorMessage;
});



});
```

Comment: because script tag has `type=module`  if type is module, js file get different scope

Comment: i removed type and it did not work, what should i change it to

Answer (score 1):

You can use `window.<YourVariableName> = <Value>`

For Example

```js
window.auth = getAuth(app);
```

Comment: this then gives me the error that createUserWithEmailAndPassword is not a function

Comment: console.log auth check if it has expected value

Comment: it does, the code works when in one javascript file

Comment: One way to solve this is to add `firebaseConfig ` to the window object and then redefine the auth  in the other file

Answer (score 0):

You should `export` your `const auth`.

**index.js**

```js
...

export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig); 
export const auth = getAuth(app);
export const db = getFirestore(app);

...
```

**auth.js**

```js
import { auth } from 'path/to/index.js';

auth //now accessible!
```